# How to make continuous loop of slides in react-responsive-carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, owl-carousel, react-responsive-carousel

I'm using react-responsive-carousel in my application. When I scroll next in last slide, it moves to first slide. But it goes to first slide passing through all slides in between. How to prevent this behaviour and make it move in a continuous loop(display first slide immediately after the last?

Here is the basic code:

```
import React from "react";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Carouel    
      infiniteLoop={true}
    >
      <div>
        <img src="./img-1.jpg"></img>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./img-2.jpg"></img>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./img-3.jpg"></img>
      </div>       
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And here is the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-responsive-carousel-complete-demo-8gkkqj?file=/src/App.js:1044-1126&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Comment: Since no one answered and still there might be some people checking this post out, this issue has been raised https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/issues/674 at previous versions of the carousel (3.2.22).

 Im using 3.2.23 just now and I experience the same issue.

What I can recommend is to install version @3.2.21 specifically.